# position of tab not updating when it is removed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am creating an application with dynamic tabs. I created tabs are able to add tabs by clicking a button and are able to remove from the back. But when I tried to remove the first tab, it is removed while after removing the first tab and tried to delete the last tab it is force closing with out-of-bounds exception.

I figure out the issue. Suppose there are 4 TABS and when I tried to delete the first tab 0th position tab (TAB 1) is deleted, now when I tried to delete the last tab say now the 4th TAB tab(now Supposedly 2nd position) it crashes as when I tried to log the position on deleting it shows the position as 3rd position.

ALl the deleting is done from viewPage adapter. and the code is :

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    int selectedTabPosition;
    private boolean doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
                            TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce) {
            doNotifyDataSetChangedOnce = false;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFrag(int position) {
        Log.e("REMOVING POSITION ",String.valueOf(position));
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        Log.e("mFragmentList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentList.size()));
        Log.e("TitleList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentTitleList.size()));
        removeTab(position);
        //destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public View getTabView(final int position) {
        Log.e("mFragmentList",String.valueOf(mFragmentList.size()));
        Log.e("TitleList",String.valueOf(mFragmentTitleList.size()));
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        TextView tabItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTabItemName);
        CircleImageView tabItemAvatar =
            (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTabItemAvatar);
        ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRemove);
        Log.e("getCount()-MAIN",String.valueOf(getCount()));
        if(getCount() == 1){
            remove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        ImageButton add = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAdd);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("Remove", "Remove");
                    if(getCount() != 1){
                        removeFrag(position);
                    }
                    else{
                       // Toast.makeText("Atleast One Tab is requied")
                    }

            }
        });
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("getCount()-ADD",String.valueOf(getCount()));
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
                ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRemove);
                if(getCount() == 1){
                    remove.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                else{
                    remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("data", "POS"+position);
                FragmentChild fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
                fragmentChild.setArguments(bundle);
                addFrag(fragmentChild, "POS"+position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                if (getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                viewPager.setCurrentItem(getCount() - 1);
                setupTabLayout();
            }
        });

        tabItemName.setText(mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
        tabItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));
        tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy);
        return view;
    }
    public void setupTabLayout() {
        selectedTabPosition = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(getTabView(i));
        }
    }
    public void destroyFragmentView(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        FragmentManager manager = ((Fragment) object).getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
        trans.remove((Fragment) object);
        trans.commit();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void removeTab(int position) {
        if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0 && tabLayout!=null) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(this);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

TAB STYLE:
[image]

Please help me to sort out this issue! what am i doing wrong here.I used a tutorial and done exactly as explained.

**FINALLY FOUND A SOLUTION**

```
if (getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(getCount() - 1);
        setupTabLayout();
```

added this piece of code to `removeFrag` function!

```
public void removeFrag(int position) {
        removeTab(position);
        Log.e("REMOVING POSITION ",String.valueOf(position));
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        Log.e("mFragmentList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentList.size()));
        Log.e("TitleList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentTitleList.size()));
        //destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(getCount() - 1);
        setupTabLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `removeFrag` function as:

```
  public void removeFrag(int position) {
        removeTab(position);
        Log.e("REMOVING POSITION ",String.valueOf(position));
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        Log.e("mFragmentList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentList.size()));
        Log.e("TitleList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentTitleList.size()));
        //destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (getCount() > 0) tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(getCount() - 1);
        setupTabLayout();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to remove..this is happening because :-

> The position of your `getView(int position)` is not updated after you are removing a tab.. so write the **function of click listener of remove(imageButton) like this..**

```
remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Remove", "Remove");
                if(getCount() != 1){

                    remove.setEnabled(false); // it here..
                    removeFrag(position);

                }
                else{
                   // Toast.makeText("Atleast One Tab is requied")
                }

        }
    });

  public void removeFrag(int position) {
    Log.e("REMOVING POSITION ",String.valueOf(position));
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
    mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
    Log.e("mFragmentList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentList.size()));
    Log.e("TitleList_REMOVE",String.valueOf(mFragmentTitleList.size()));
    removeTab(position);
    //destroyFragmentView(viewPager, position, fragment);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    setupTabLayout(); // do the setup of tablayout after removing
}
```

**Edit** Do one more thing dont forget to disable the button.. because if the user *clicks the button two consecutive times..in a flash* the might crash..

`remove.setEnabled(false);` **disable and enable again at getView(int position) again..**

```
getView(int position)
 {
   ........
   remove.setEnabled(true); //enable
     }
```

**Update :-**

```
public void removeTab(int position) {
    if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0 && tabLayout!=null) {
        tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        //notifyDataSetChanged(); //notify here
        removeTabPage(position);

    }
    //viewPager.setAdapter(this);

}
```

> You also need to remove the page..

```
public void removeTabPage(int position) {
if (!mFragmentList.isEmpty() && position<mFragmentList.size()) {
      mFragmentList.remove(position);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: where should we call `remove.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: I got this error:`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged! Expected adapter item count: 4, found: 3 Pager id: com.eazypos.app:id/my_viewpager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager Problematic adapter: class com.eazypos.app.ViewPagerAdapter`

Comment: Still same error.. Error line is :`tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);`

Comment: Do i have to remove the `setupTabLayout();` from `removeFrag`

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: where did you notify?

Comment: when to call this function?

Comment: no mPagerAdapter required.. just.. check updated.. in your case its `mFragmentList` not `tabItems`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165543/discussion-between-santanu-sur-and-karthik-cp).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Context context, ViewPager viewPager,
                            TabLayout tabLayout) {
        super(manager);
        this.context = context;
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
        this.tabLayout = tabLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFrag(int position) {
        removeTab(position);
        Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
        mFragmentList.remove(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(this);
    }

    public View getTabView(final int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_item, null);
        TextView tabItemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewTabItemName);
        CircleImageView tabItemAvatar =
                (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewTabItemAvatar);
        ImageButton remove = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonRemove);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Remove", "Remove");
                removeFrag(position);
            }
        });

        tabItemName.setText(mFragmentTitleList.get(position));
        tabItemName.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.background_light));

        switch (mFragmentTitleList.get(position)) {
            case "Gaiduk":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.gaiduk);
                break;
            case "Nguyen":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.avatar);
                break;
            case "Balakin":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.balakin);
                break;
            case "Golovin":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.golovin);
                break;
            case "Ovcharov":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.ovcharov);
                break;
            case "Solovienko":
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.solovei);
                break;
            default:
                tabItemAvatar.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy);
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }



    public void removeTab(int position) {
        if (tabLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference`. this error still

Comment: I have zipped my code : try with this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f7n1acleosut8uu/EazyPos.zip?dl=0